# Is JSR 296 (Swing Application Framework) stable enough to use? If not, what are the other options for small Swing apps?

Tags: java, swing, frameworks

Eclipse RCP and Netbeans Platform are too big for the smaller apps that I work on, but I would still like to use a framework to make my apps more maintainable and consistent.

Are there any other small frameworks that would be useful here?

Comment: what do you mean by "too big", a minimal Eclipse RCP app has very few plugins in it, as long as you only include the ones you need that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can consider it stable, at Sun nobody has worked on it for years.
Yes I'm a bit sarcastic here but that's the simple truth, nobody at Sun seems to care about it.

More seriously, I have used it in several applications (version 1.03, the latest) quite successfully. However, there are some bugs that you may have to fix yourself if they are showstoppers for you (I had to fix some myself).

A word of caution: don't use the latest SVN (or is it CVS? I can't remember) source, but exclusively rely on 1.03; the latest committed source is rather a regression than an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

We are using Swing App Framework in production for years. It is stable. Some things could be better, but we added some of our own enhancements.

As you probably know there is a team of engineers at Sun now who are actively working towards making it part of JDK.

Comment: But it won't be part of the JDK7, as anounced today at http://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2009/08/saf_and_jdk7.html

Comment: That really doesn't matter because SAF can be used as third-party library.